# Python - Only print lines if contains the elements of a tuple from a List

Tags: python, list, loops, text

I've the following text file:

```
We are playing football at World Cup
teste
We are playing football
Playing test 
World Cup Football
```

And I only want to extract the lines that contains (World Cup and Football) or ('Playing', 'test ').

For example, based on my text file I only want to extract this:

```
We are playing football at World Cup
Playing test 
World Cup Footbal
```

Basically I only want to extract if the line contains the two values from each tuple.

For that I am trying the following code:

```
file = 'text.txt'
words = [('Football','World Cup'), ('Playing test ')]
with open(file, "r") as ins:
    for line in ins:
        if all(x in line.lower() for x in words):
            print(line)
```

But with my code I am having the following error:

```
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not tuple
```

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Your code is ambiguous. make it clear for second element of words list. Is it `('playing test')` or `('playing', 'test')`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with combination of `any` and `all`:

```
if any(all(words.lower() in line.lower() for words in word_tuples) for word_tuples in words)
```

You can check any from the list of words and all from items of the list.

(*Testing without file*)

```
# Note: second element needs to be tuple else causes unexpected results
words = [('Football','World Cup'), ('Playing test',)] 
ins = ["We are playing football at World Cup",
       "teste",
       "We are playing football",
       "Playing test",
       "World Cup Football"]

for line in ins:
    if any(all(words.lower() in line.lower() for words in word_tuples) for word_tuples in words):
        print(line)
```

Output:

```
We are playing football at World Cup
Playing test
World Cup Football
```

As mentioned in the comment below, if second element is not tuple, it causes unexpected result. Using test example, following shows error as it is comparing if all characters are same instead of words:

```
x = "test palying"
if all(w.lower() in x for w in words[1]):
    print("ERROR")
```

Comment: How is your code working when second element of words isn't a tuple. Also there is ambiguity in  op's code as he is telling two things about that second element.

Comment: @Vicrobot Thank you! I did not realize that. I think it causes unexpected result so, to fix the second element needs to be `tuple` as well i.e. `('Playing test',)`

Answer (score 0):

You were really close, you just needed one more loop:

```
file = 'text.txt'
words = [('Football','World Cup'), ('Playing test ')]
with open(file, "r") as ins:
    for line in ins:
        for tup in words:
            if all(word.lower() in line.lower() for word in tup):
                print(line)
```